# DotNetOpenAuth RequestUserAuthorization callback

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth

I am attempting to get a user authorization token with the following:

```
public static void RequestAuthorization(WebConsumer consumer)
{
    if (consumer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("consumer");

    Uri callback = new Uri("http://www.ihighfive.com/"); //test url until app is external

    var extraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
        //need to pass this as extra, but leave the value blank
        { "oauth_token", string.Empty} 
    };

    var req = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, extraParams, null);    
    consumer.Channel.Send(req);
}
```

But I receive back an error:

```
{ "error": { "message" : "oauth_callback is required",  "isFriendly" : false} }
```

If I modify the above code and manually include the oauth_callback paramater I get more favorable results

```
var extraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    //need to pass this as extra, but leave the value blank
    { "oauth_token", string.Empty},
    { "oauth_callback", "http://www.ihighfive.com/" },
};
```

So passing the callback argument to .PrepareRequestUserAuthorization() seems to not be including oauth_callback with the request. Am I somehow using the callback parameter incorrectly?

**--edit--**

Further investigation shows that the oauth_callback parameter is not getting included if the ServiceProviderDescription is set to ProtocolVersion.V10. If it is either set to ProtocolVersion.V10a, or not set at all, the oauth_callback gets included in the request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DotNetOpenAuth Expected IProtocolMessage message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233943/dotnetopenauth-expected-iprotocolmessage-message)

Comment: These issues are both trying to talk to the same endpoint, but I think they may be separate issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is then, "why isn't oauth_callback being included automatically", your further investigation is the answer.  It's a new parameter added in OAuth 1.0a, so when you set the version to 1.0, the parameter is omitted.