# DotNetOpenAuth Expected IProtocolMessage message

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to request an authentication token:

```
public static void RequestAuthorization(WebConsumer consumer)
{
    var extraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
        { "oauth_token", string.Empty},
        { "oauth_callback", "http://www.ihighfive.com/" },
    };

    var req = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, extraParams, null);    
    consumer.Channel.Send(req);
}
```

Problem is, when I run .PrepareRequestUserAuthorization() I get the following error

> Expected IProtocolMessage message but received no recognizable
>   message.

Inspecting the request/response with Fiddler, I can see that the response returns(values obfusticated):

```
{ "oauth_token" : "this-is-the-oauth-token", 
"oauth_token_secret" : "this-is-the-oauth-secret-token", 
"oauth_callback_confirmed" : true, 
"urlToSendUserTo" : "http://blah.blah.com/api/OAuthAuthorizeToken.aspx?oauth_token=token-value-is-really-long"}
```

To me, this appears to be a good response. If I visit the urlToSendUserTo, it works, and then passes me through to my initial callback url. So I guess DNOA is having problems parsing the response, but I can't see why.

Comment: Check the mime types sent and received. Looks like the response is `json/text`, but your `WebConsumer` maybe expecting something else. What is your WebConsumer sending in the `accept` header?

Comment: There does not appear to be any accept header in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What protocol is the server using?  It's not OAuth 1.0 but you're using OAuth 1.0 classes in DotNetOpenAuth.  [OAuth 1.0 mandates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.1) that the response be in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format but in your snippet of the response it's clearly in JSON instead.

Also, I've never seen the `urlToSendUserTo` parameter in any spec, and I don't know why you're sending an empty `oauth_token` as an extra parameter in the request.

It seems like you and/or the server are speaking very different languages.

Comment: The server claims to be using OAuth 1.0a (https://www.dialawg.com/api/#nav=view%3DapiIntro). That empty oauth_token MAY be omitted (as is mentioned at the bottom of the link you posted). I've tried both with and without it.

Comment: @CoreyDownie I would suggest you email those dialawg folks and ask them why they're sending you JSON responses then.  That's definitely not OAuth 1.0a compliant.